# Do i have to re-archive adhoc app after adding device?

Tags: ios

I distribute my app for tests by putting link to plist on my server and i'm wondering if i need to re-install provisioning profile and archive and send ipa back to the server after i will add new udids. Also is there a way to distribute for tests without the need to know those udids?

Comment: briefly, yes. you must do it again.

Comment: You can also distribute with enterprise distribution instead of adhoc. But getting an enterprise account is not that easy.

Comment: It sounds interesting however website says that enterprise accounts cannot submit to app store, so i would have to have to accounts then, is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you have to add UDID in your provisioning profile, then download it and make build with this fresh provisioning profile. Without this newly added devices could not install the application.